# How to identify the request is coming from a human input or attack script?

Tags: security, web, identity

There is a input form, end user can register as a regular user. off course the attacker can also write a script to input the form with spam data.
Besides a captcha verfication, is there any other method to prevent from attacking?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. I dont think any way to differentiate. Even though input by user, at the end it is a program/script being executed (which is equal to automated script if inputs are hardcoded).

Here are some [alternatives for captcha.](http://www.sitepoint.com/captcha-problems-alternatives/) I think BOA uses picture based test.